# linearize a nonlinear constraint for LP

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have the following optimization

min (x(t)*a(t)-y(t)*b(t))
s.t

x(t)*y(t)=0

x(t)>0
y(t)>0

How I can linearize the nonlinear constraint ?

b(t) and a(t) are constant vectors.

Comment: Is any variable binary or integer. If not, it cannot be linearized

Comment: You could formulate this as a (linear) MIP: the complementarity condition can be interpreted as an "OR" constraint.

Comment: True, I was a bit unclear. You can perform a big-M representation with binary variables, but there is no way to derive a simple continuous LP model.

Comment: You can probably encourage x,y to be sparse maybe with an L_1 norm. That is logically what $x(t)*y(t) = 0$ means - one of them must be 0. Wait, $*$ is multiplication and not convolution, right?

Answer (score 1):

If you allow binary variables, the standard big-M model is

$$0\leq x \leq M\delta_1, 0\leq y \leq M\delta_2, \delta_1 + \delta_2 \leq 1$$